# Common Qt Producer/Consumer Example: What is the point of multithreading here?

Tags: multithreading, qt

While trying to figure out how to implement a Producer/Consumer Queue in Qt, I stumpled upon several SO answers, blogs and sites linking to this site:

[You're doing it wrong...](https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong)

I got the point of this site, but people are usually referring to the code example which is in the referenced blog:

[Threading without the headache](https://www.qt.io/blog/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache)

The blog has a small code example attached, the core of it being posted by KornP in this SO answer:

[Qt moveToThread() vs calling new thread when do we use each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152609/qt-movetothread-vs-calling-new-thread-when-do-we-use-each#5153990)

So if you take a closer look we have the following behaviour:

1. Producer P produces an item, while Consumer C waits for events to appear in its event loop.
2. P forwards the produced data through a signal and returns to event loop idling.
3. C receives the signal in its event loop and consumes the data.
4. C emits a signal to the producer thread and returns to event loop idling.
5. Start over from 1.

In other words: while P is producing, C does nothing and while C is producing, P does nothing.

What is the point of having a producer and consumer **like this** in two different threads?
Wouldn't a single thread accomplish exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this simple case, yes, there's no real benefit in using threads other than showing how threads work I guess. It's still interesting though: P's event loop keeps on running while the actual work is done by C. This is what you want in order to keep the user interface (which P might very well be) responsive.

Things get more interesting with concrete examples. Suppose C comsumes data by storing it in a buffer, and dumps it to a file when the buffer has enough data. This dumping might take while, but P can just continue it's business putting data in the queue without noticing C is busy nor without any slowdown.